# Wordpress post not executing shortcode until updated

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, plugin-gravity-forms

Quick query, I'm using Gravity Forms so my users can create CPTs but I'm finding that when the post is created it shows the shortcode rather than executing it. Once I click update from the post backend the shortcode executes fine.

Would like to diagnose this however failing that is there anyway to force it ?

Comment: Share the relevant code...

Comment: Posts are created with the gform + cpt plugin. Not sure which section of code would help.

Comment: Question was really is there anyway of forcing all shortcode to be executed regardless of how its generated or where it is on the frontend.

Comment: And potentially is there any reason a gform generated post would not execute shortcode until it is updated